# How to stop this weird auto reloading in IE

Tags: .htaccess, internet-explorer, mod-rewrite

I have developed this website in PHP...

I have used htaccess to rewrite

1. non-www urls to www
2. add a trailing slash if needed
3. rewrite the url niecdelhi.ac.in/page_to_visit to index.php?inc=page_to_visit.php

For example:-
niecdelhi.ac.in/jobs_at_niec/
***rewrites to***
niecdelhi.ac.in/index.php?inc=jobs_at_niec.php

The website runs smooth on Firefox and Chrome but it keeps on auto reloading indefinite times in IE.

Please help me in solving this problem.

Visit this link to see the problem: http://www.niecdelhi.ac.in/jobs_at_niec/

---

My .htaccess file looks like below:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[^\.]+[^/]$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?inc=$1&%1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

**Edit 1:** added [QSA] flag instead of {QUERY_STRING}

**Edit 2:** added [R=301,L] to non-www to www url rewrite.

Comment: Are you sure its your .htaccess causing this? It should behave the same whatever browser you are using.

Comment: Try running Fiddler ( http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/ ) to monitor the HTTP Traffic that IE is sending and receiving, see how it compares with what Chrome and Firefox are doing.

Comment: Note, there's no need for the `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}` and the `%1`.  Instead add the `[QSA]` flag. (query string append)

Comment: As @Jleagle says, this sounds like it could be JavaScript rather than something serverside.

Comment: Take a look at the errors IE is throwing. There maybe errors in the error console on firefox too.

Comment: @Jleagle I am not sure what is causing this but I suspect htaccess maybe the reason because every page is reloading except the HOME PAGE i.e. index.php. I do not have any other complex code except htaccess.

Comment: @glenatron ok, I will try using fiddler and post the results here. I have not used fiddler before...

Comment: @Michael Thanks for this info, I didnt know this.. I will remove the RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} :)

Comment: In Firefox I got redirected to `/index.php?inc=jobs_at_niec/` .. but in Internet Explorer 9 it shows me the home page after redirect. Even if I go directly to that page `/index.php?inc=jobs_at_niec/` in IE, I still got redirected to homepage. **It is definitely the JavaScript**. Firefox shows that there is failed request to `/?event=refresh`, in IE it must be going trough which causing the redirect. So ... start digging JS.

Comment: Side note: having `index.php?inc=page_to_visit.php` is really bad practice and is not considered secure (unless you are doing strong security checks of that parameter)

Comment: @LazyOne Bro, Do not go to `/index.php?inc=jobs_at_niec/` it is the internal rewrite that I talked about in the post... Instead go to http://www.niecdelhi.ac.in/jobs_at_niec/ to see the problem...Thanks...

Comment: @Sharad I do go there, and got redirected to the home page in IE (only once,not infinite redirects), but not in Firefox (here I do see jobs page). It's a client side issue for sure -- and it only triggers in IE.

Comment: @LazyOne In IE8, i am getting redirected infinite times to the same page....(whatever page I visit) Are you sure, you went to my link and redirected to home page only once ??

Comment: @Sharad Yes, I **was** redirected to homepage -- that's for sure -- tried it quite few times with the same result. But I have tried again now (after your comment).. and now it does infinite redirect -- don't know what you have changed there, but now I do see the same behaviour as you. I suggest - disable all 3rd party scripts (that are loaded from other domains - e.g. Google Analytics) and try reproducing the issue. If it will start working -- enable those disabled scripts one by one until you reproduce the issue. Maybe even start with disabling ALL scripts (even jquery) and enable one by one.

Comment: Maybe that part at bottom of of page makes IE crazy: <script type="text/javascript">navigate('','','');</script>

Comment: @Arvo WTF nice observation. I dont know how, why and where that part of script came from, but removing it solved the problem.. Arvo, Thanks a ton... sorry If that was a silly error..lol.. :) :)

Comment: @LazyOne Thanks for ur efforts, YES you were write.. That was indeed a Third Party script causing the problem... Thanks dude... :) :)

Answer (score 1):

Not really a full answer to your question but I think you should make the non-www to www redirect a permanent 301 redirect `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]`
and mark it as [L] (don't process other rules afterwards).

Take a look here: http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum92/1017.htm

Not sure if this will solve your problems but worth a try.

EDIT:
Your problem is definitely client side. Disabling JavaScript on the browser fixes the issue or neverending refresh.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer, I have made the non-www to www redirect as [R=301,L] but the problem remains the same.

Comment: Ah, I was hoping it could be a redirect loop caused by the rules but it seems that I was wrong. Anyways, non-www redirect should be 301 permanent so it wasn't a waste.